# How can I eliminate the negative part of this graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, draw

While writing this article about demodulation for my students, I wanted to draw just the positive part of this function `\cos(10*\pi*\x r)(1.5*\cos(0.75*\pi*\x r)+2)`but I don't know how to eliminate the negative part of it, here's the code but it compiles the whole function, any helpful idea ?

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
\draw[-latex, smooth] (0,0)--(8,0) node[above] {$t$};
\draw[-latex, smooth] (0,-3.8)--(0,3.8) node[right] {$u$};
\draw[thick] plot[domain=0:7.5,samples=5000] (\x,{cos(10*pi*\x r)*(1.5*cos(0.75*pi*\x r)+2)});
\node at (3.8,3.8) {La tension modulée $s(t)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Here's how it should be (approximately lol) :

[image]

Comment: Use `max(0,cos(10*pi*\x r)*(1.5*cos(0.75*pi*\x r)+2))`

Comment: @PaulGaborit How should it be inserted in the code ?

Comment: Insert it to replace the current function.

Comment: @PaulGaborit Yeah I did it, thank you Sir !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @PaulGaborit for his advice here's the result :

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
\draw[-latex, smooth] (0,0)--(8,0) node[above] {$t$};
\draw[-latex, smooth] (0,-3.8)--(0,3.8) node[right] {$u$};
\draw[thick] plot[domain=0:7.5,samples=5000] (\x,{max(0,cos(10*pi*\x r)*(1.5*cos(0.75*pi*\x r)+2))});
\node at (3.8,3.8) {La tension modulée $s(t)$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]